# firebase Analytics : Android app uninstall stats

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I installed Firebase SDK and add below two lines to MainActivity.java

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

I need uninstall stats (app_remove event) - like which device user uninstalled the app. Do I need to add more firebase api or is this setup enough?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the `app_remove` stats, there is no need to add any Java code. Whenever user uninstalls an app, it gets updated in the console under `events` section.

[image]

Comment: It  will also give device/OS information of that un-installed device?

Comment: @lakshmipathi No it doesn't give device/OS information but it tells how many users from a particular country uninstalled the app along with their gender and age.

Comment: Does firebase has option to find out that info. Something like - we can hook to this uninstall event & upload device/OS into firebase ? Is that possible (I'm pretty new to firebase, dont have much idea about it)

Comment: @lakshmipathi I have no idea about that :(, I suggest you to ask this question on [Firebase Twitter](https://twitter.com/Firebase) with the hashtag #AskFirebase. On Youtube, they weekly release a video that answers questions tagged with #AskFirebase. They might answer this question.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Did you find any good way to track uninstalls at user level? I'm struggling with Segment.io/Clevertap but unable to get data at one place till now i.e. in segment or our own database.

Comment: is it possible to know the last active activity before uninstall?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to link your Firebase with BigQuery and query your it. Read more about it here: https://medium.com/me/stats/post/c4657e2465c6