# How to track events for user who uninstall app in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to track events on user who uninstall my game. I want to know how many levels user passed before they uninstal my game. Is there.any way to get list od this kind of users and see analytics for each user separately?

What firebase tools should I use to get thise informations?
Im using android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On Android uninstalls are tracked automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239646/firebase-analytics-android-app-uninstall-stats

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer based on the link you provided :)

Comment: I now that there is uninstall event, but I want to know what custom events occurred before uninstall for thay user

Comment: Hi @Jovan, did you find a solution?

Comment: is there any way to find uninstallation of IOS, by default analytics track only android

Answer (score 6):

The best approach it's to use [Firebase Analytics for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) with [event logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) which automatically log app uninstall using the `app_remove` event.
You can find a complete list of automatically logged event for both Android and iOS [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485)

Moreover you should save events everytime the user passes a level in your game or performs an action you are interested in.

> After some time you will have enough data to know exactly where most
>   people stop playing the game or uninstall it and you can start corrective actions trying to prevent this (or at least affecting some of them)

*NOTE: answer updated thanks to Frank Van Puffelen comment*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to track user flow , something like stream view but sorted by some event. I want to now what events( i will add custom events in my game ) occurr when user uninstall app.

Comment: @Jovan I suggest you to think twice about it. You should send an event for EVERY user and distinguish about them. It's something custom you need to build from scratch and probably has no real value at all. Because users can have 10 reasons to uninstall your app and even tracking all their actions you won't known the truth for all of them. Aggregating results with Analytics it's better, if you have 10.000 events for level 1 passed and 1000 events for level 2 passed, you immediately know the problem is between level 1 and 2 and so on....

Answer (score 1):

Use simple google analytics and define event method from it or also you can use firebase analytics to track your app performance and log.